# Scraping a website with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, css-selectors, nokogiri, web-scraping

I am using Nokogiri to scrape a website and am running into an issue when I try to grab a field from a table. I am using [selector gadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) to find the CSS selector of the table. I am grabbing data from a [government website that details information on motor carriers](http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&query_string=800585).

The method that I am using looks like:

```
def scrape_database
  url = "http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&query_string=#{self.dot}#Inspections"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  self.name = doc.at_css("tr:nth-child(4) .queryfield").text
  self.address = doc.at_css("tr:nth-child(6) .queryfield").text
end
```

I grab all of the fields in the upper table using that syntax and the method operates fine, however I am having issues with the crash rate/inspections table below it.

Here is what I am using to grab that info:

```
self.vehicle_inspections = doc.at_css("center:nth-child(13) tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(2)").text

undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
```

If I remove `text` from the end of this, the method runs but doesn't grab any relevant information (obviously). I am assuming this is due to the complicated selector that I am using to grab the field, but am not quite sure.

Has anyone run into a similar problem and can you give me some advice?

Comment: Please add some sample HTML demonstrating the problem. If the page the URL points to were to disappear, your question wouldn't really help anyone encountering the problem in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that error means that your CSS selector is not finding the information; `at_css` is returning `nil`, and `nil.text` is not valid. You can guard against it like so:

```
insp = doc.at_css("long example css selector")
self.vehicle_inspections = insp && insp.text
```

However, it sounds to me like you "need" this data. Since you have not provided with the HTML page nor the CSS selectors, I can't help you craft a working CSS or XPath selector.

*For future questions, or an edit to this one, note that actual (pared-down) code is strongly preferred over hand waving and loose descriptions of what your code looks like. If you show us the HTML page, or a relevant snippet, and describe which element/text/attribute you want, we can tell you how to select it.*

I see six tables on that page. Which is the "crash rate/inspections" table? Given that your URL includes `#Inspections` on the end, I'm assuming you're talking about the two tables immediately underneath the "Inspections/Crashes In US" section. Here are XPath selectors that match each:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&query_string=800585"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
table1 = doc.at_xpath('//table[@summary="Inspections"][preceding::h4[.//a[@name="Inspections"]]]')
table2 = doc.at_xpath('//table[@summary="Crashes"][preceding::h4[.//a[@name="Inspections"]]]')

# Find a row by index (1 is the first row)
vehicle_inspections    = table1.at_xpath('.//tr[2]/td').text.to_i

# Find a row by header text
out_of_service_drivers = table1.at_xpath('.//tr[th="Out of Service"]/td[2]').text.to_i

p [ vehicle_inspections, out_of_service_drivers ]
#=> [6, 0]

tow_crashes = table2.at_xpath('.//tr[th="Crashes"]/td[3]').text.to_i
p tow_crashes
#=> 0
```

The XPath queries may look intimidating. Let me explain how they work:

1. `//table[@summary="Inspections"][preceding::h4[.//a[@name="Inspections"]]]`

   - **`//table`**  find a `<table>` at any level of the document
   - **`[@summary="Inspections"]`**  …but only if it has a `summary` attribute with this value
   - **`[preceding::h4…]`** …and only if you can find an `<h4>` element earlier in the document
   - **`[.//a…]`** …specifically, a `<h4>` that has an `<a>` somewhere underneath it

     - **`[@name="Inspections"]`** …and that `<a>` has to have a `name` attribute with this text.

   This would actually match two tables (there's another `summary="Inspections"` table later on the page), but using `at_xpath` finds the first matching table.
2. `.//tr[2]/td`

   - **`.`** Starting at the current node (this table)
   - **`//tr[2]`** …find the second `<tr>` that is a descendant at any level
   - **`/td`** …and then find the `<td>` children of that.

   Again, because we're using `at_xpath` we find the first matching `<td>`.
3. `.//tr[th="Out of Service"]/td[2]`

   - **`.`** Starting at the current node (this table)
   - **`//tr`** …find any `<tr>` that is a descendant at any level

     - **`[th="Out of Service]`** …but only those `<tr>` that have a `<th>` child with this text
   - **`/td[2]`** …and then find the second `<td>` children of those.

   In this case there is only one `<tr>` that matches the criteria, and thus only one `<td>` that matches, but we still use `at_xpath` so that we get that node directly instead of a NodeSet with a single element in it.

The goal here (and with any screen scraping) is to latch onto meaningful values on the page, not arbitrary indices.

For example, I could have written my `table1` xpath as:

```
# Find the first table with this summary
table1 = doc.at_xpath('//table[@summary="Inspections"][1]')
```

…or even…

```
# Find the 20th table on the page
//table[20]
```

However, those are *fragile*. Someone adding a new section to the page, or code that happens to add or remove a formatting table would cause those expressions to break. You want to hunt for strong attributes and text that likely won't change, and anchor your searches based on that.

*The `vehicle_inspections` XPath is similarly fragile, relying on the ordering of rows instead of the label text for the row.*

Comment: sure here is the example page that I am trying to grab information from: [safer](http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&query_string=800789) There are two main tables of data that I am looking at grabbing, the personal data and the inspections/crashes table below it. I will update the selectors above to show what I am using and what is not working.

Comment: @demondeac11 Great, that helps. I've edited my answer to get what I *think* you want, explained how the XPath works so that you can perhaps craft your own queries, and tried to describe why using CSS selectors based on indices are too fragile.

Comment: This was honestly the best answer I have ever received on stack overflow. This is a problem that has been flummoxing me for a while, and I am so glad that you have shown me not only how to solve it but how to go about using xpath so I can solve future problems on my own.